# Why does this program in Dennis Ritchie's "The C Programming Language" not work?

Tags: c

I'm starting to learn C and came across the following program in Dennis Ritchie's *The C Programming Language* (2nd edition):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000

int getline(char line[], int maxline);
void copy(char to[], char from[]);

int main()
{
    int len;
    int max;
    char line[MAXLINE];    /* current input line */
    char longest[MAXLINE]; /* longest line saved here */

    max = 0;

    while ((len = getline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0)
    {
        if (len > max)
        {
            max = len;
            copy(longest, line);
        }
    }
    if (max > 0)
        printf("%s", longest);
    return 0;
}

int getline(char s[], int lim)
{
    int c, i;

    for (i = 0; i < lim - 1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i)
        s[i] = c;
    if (c == '\n')
    {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}

void copy(char to[], char from[])
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while ((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0')
        ++i;
}
```

When I run this program exactly as is, it does not compile because there are conflicting definitions of `getline`. It turns out there is a `getline` in `stdio.h`, and that's where the conflict comes from. I assume this is non-standard or was added to the library after the book was published. In any case, that error was easily fixed by simply changing the name of the function to `getLine`.

After making that change, the program compiles but never actually completes. What I did notice is that `getLine` adds both a newline character and a null terminator (`\0`) to the character array `s`, and the value it returns, while it is meant to be the length of the character array, is actually that length + 1. Modifying the function to return `i - 1` instead of `i` fixes the issue.

My question is: why does it fix the issue? I doubt that it's a typo, but maybe that's possible? Or could it be a compiler issue? Do some compilers count a null terminator as a character (i.e. to be included in the length of the character array) while others don't?

I should also say that I'm using an M1 MacBook, so I guess it's possible that the code translates to different machine code which creates different results?

EDIT:

The following is the modified code that works for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000

int getLine(char line[], int maxline);
void copy(char to[], char from[]);

int main()
{
    int len;
    int max;
    char line[MAXLINE];    /* current input line */
    char longest[MAXLINE]; /* longest line saved here */

    max = 0;

    while ((len = getLine(line, MAXLINE)) > 0)
    {
        if (len > max)
        {
            max = len;
            copy(longest, line);
        }
    }
    if (max > 0)
        printf("%s", longest);
    return 0;
}

int getLine(char s[], int lim)
{
    int c, i;

    for (i = 0; i < lim - 1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i)
        s[i] = c;
    if (c == '\n')
    {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i - 1;
}

void copy(char to[], char from[])
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while ((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0')
        ++i;
}
```

Also, when I say that the original code never completes, I mean that I can type anything, press enter, type some more, press enter, etc. then finally just press enter without typing (the code is checking for an array of length zero, so this is where it should print out the line of max length and exit), and the program continues running.

Comment: Show the code that you're actually running, i.e., after the correction to make it compile. Otherwise, it's not clear what you actually did, and you may have messed up the correction.

Comment: It's worth noting that this book is more of a historical artifact than a valuable learning tool at this point. ANSI C has been improved on by several major revisions to the C standard.

Comment: `but never actually completes` do you input anything to the program? The program works fine here without any modifications. Doing `i - 1` should have no effect (except well it could break empty lines with no newline handling).

Comment: Note: C is not something that will spontaneously behave differently on an ARM CPU unless you're making a lot of assumptions about [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). This code is too simple for that to be a factor.

Comment: Tip: Try and keep the signatures used in your function *declarations* and *definitions* absolutely identical. There's no reason to have two different variable names here, as that's usually a sign that something slipped.

Comment: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html _"Both getline() and getdelim() were originally GNU extensions. They were standardized in POSIX.1-2008."_  So it is a POSIX function and not an ISO function.

Comment: It looks like getLine returns the correct length.  The string "foo\n" has length 4.

Comment: `getLine()` doesn't add a newline character. It reads until it gets a newline character, and the newline is included in the result. Just like the standard `fgets()`.

Comment: Are you on Linux/Mac/Unix or Windows? Type Ctrl-D or Ctrl-Z on a blank line to end the input.

Comment: returning `i -1` is the same as checking `getLine()... > 1`, which indeed would make the program stop on an empty line. I think the program was intended to handle empty lines normally. To stop the program you have  "stop typing" as in "trigger EOF". When running the program, type something and then press ctrl+D.

Comment: It returns the length of the _string_, not the _"length of the character array"_.  A better solution would be to replace the `\n` with `\0` rather then appending it, then not increment `i` if that is the way you wanted it to behave.

Comment: @ninjalj @kamilcuk ah! I didn't know that ctrl+D is EOF, that's good to know. But isn't the program supposed to treat newlines and EOFs similarly, to judge by this: `for (i = 0; i < lim - 1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i)`?

Comment: @GaiusDavidius: nope, look at the `if` below. Think how the program would behave if fed a file with paragraphs separated by blank (!= empty) lines.

Answer (score 1):

> When I run this program exactly as is, it does not compile because there are conflicting definitions of `getline`

There is a [`getline`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) function offered as an extension in some implementations, and its prototype is conflicting with the example in the book.  That's most likely what's happening with you.  Awesome as K&R is, it's an *old* book at this point and out of date in many respects.

The easiest way to get around this is to rename your `getline` function to `getLine` or `get_line` or something else.  Alternately you'll need to *undefine* `_GNU_SOURCE` or `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` before including `stdio.h`, either in your code or on the command line.

Comment: If you're using gcc or something compatible with it, compiling with `std=cXX` (XX == 90, 99, 11, 17) will remove the declaration of the non-standard `getline` function and let the original code compile.